# How add media_content attribute with PyRSS2Gen feed?

Tags: python, xml, rss, feed

I need to add media_content attribute to rss feeds. I am using PyRSS2Gen package for generating feeds. I have attached title,link,description,guid etc with rss feeds. But I could'nt add media_content. Can anyone help me?